# Angular5 - How to check if a module is loaded

Tags: angular, module, navigation, angular5

in Angular 5 I need to know if the module has already been loaded in order not to show the spinner.
At the moment my code is this:

```
    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService, private router: Router, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        console.log(this.router);
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.isSpinnerVisible = true;
        } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError) {
            this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
        }
    }, () => {
        this.isSpinnerVisible = false;
    });
}
```

In this way, if the module has already been loaded, I still show the module for a tenth of a second.
Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use global variables (yes, it's not advised, but they exist for a reason, so take advantage of it)

```
export class MyAppModule {
  constructor() {
    if (!window['loaded_modules']) { window['loaded_modules'] = []; }
    window['loaded_modules'].push(this.constructor.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to use this solution. Maybe centralizing the somewhere. Then, if there is someone with another solution. I'm waiting :)

Comment: Just as an improvement to this. Add the loaded modules to your types.

You could do something like this:
`interface Window { loaded_modules: string[]; }`